# Passing props when linking to same react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I want to link to the same component by clicking on different links but I want to return different things depending on the link I click on.

so I have this:

```
{this.props.children}
<Link to="channel"> General </Link>
<br />
<Link to="channel"> Random </Link>
```

Then in my render I have this

```
<Route path="channel" foo="General" component={Channel}></Route>
<Route path="channel" foo="Random" component={Channel}></Route>
```

That calls the Channel component:

```
export default class Channel extends React.Component{

  render(){
    return (
      <h1> {this.props.route.foo} </h1>

    )
  }
}
```

But I want it to return the value of the prop foo but every time it returns "General". How can I link the routing to the `<Link to` part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your paths should be different. Both routes have `path="channel"` and only the first route is registered by react-router. Do something like:

```
<Route path="channel" foo="General" component={Channel}></Route>
<Route path="channel2" foo="Random" component={Channel}></Route>
```

And your links should be:

```
{this.props.children}
<Link to="channel"> General </Link>
<br />
<Link to="channel2"> Random </Link>
```